# c++ Template linking error when I put template in another class to instantiate?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I don't know if this makes a difference, but I am using VS c++ 6.0

Linking...

```
vid3Dlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: double __thiscall Image::jdlMin(double,double)" (?jdlMin@Image@@QAENNN@Z)
Debug/vid3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
```

I tried this also:

```
template  <class T> T Image::jdlMin( T a, T b )
```

and I get same error.

```
  //Image.h
    class Image  
    {
    public:
        Image();
        virtual ~Image();
        template <class T>  T jdlMin( T a, T b );
    }

//Image.cpp
Image::Image()
{
}

Image::~Image()
{
}    

template  <class T> T jdlMin( T a, T b )
//I tried this also:  template  <class T> T Image::jdlMin( T a, T b )
{
    return ( a < b );// ? a : b;
}


//CVid3Dlg.cpp
void CVid3Dlg::exTemplate()
{
    Image *im = new Image();
    int s=0;
    s = im->jdlMin((double)3,(double)4); //

}
```

Comment: I believe `typename T` is preferred over `class T`.

Comment: maybe I should just use void pointers

Comment: Pft, absolutely not, templates are much more C++-like, if they do the job, you need.

Comment: Is the problem in the instantiation of it "im" ?  I had done what people thought was the problem, but like I said it yields the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time, i compiled it (under VC++ 10) to test the functionality:

```
//Image.h

template<typename T>
class Image  
{
    public:
        Image() {};
        virtual ~Image() {};
        T jdlMin( T a, T b );
};


//Image.cpp
#include "Image.h"


template <typename T> 
T Image<T>::jdlMin( T a, T b )
{ 
 return ( a < b ); 
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Image<double> *im = new Image<double>();

    double s = 0.0;
    s = im->jdlMin( 3.0 , 4.0 );

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps...

Bye the way, i took a look into a good C++ documentation: "class T" and "typename T" have exactly the same meaning and behave exactly the same way... ;)

Comment: this will work if the implementation is in the definition.  But I need it in a "cpp" file.  And there it breaks down to the errors I have listed.

Comment: I gave you a point for something that works... I will give you the rest if you can get the other working as well, as I showed above.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this... as I listed earlier I am using VS C++ 6.0.  Templates in the header, that do work, the compiler won't update to the change in code unless I change the numbers being passed.  I have read 6.0 has problems with templates.  So this works in VC10 but not sure if it works in VC6.0 ??  Anyway I will select this one.

Comment: Yeah, VC6 is not very good in templates... do you really use VC6? The best compiler for me so far was VC++ 7.1 (Vc.Net 2003). Very stable, very fast, very small (800mb). VC 8, 9, 10 is shit... slow, compiler issues, deploy problems... VC7.1 is cool... go and get it :)
15$ at ebay...

Comment: Are templates just as fast or slower than just overloading functions of different types.  Do they consume more memory in overhead?  I stress it as a concern, since I could apply this to very large matrices say 1GB to 2GB of data. ??

Comment: In my opinion its the same overhead to use templates or overloaded methods.

The compiler generates template functions/classes when used, like overloaded functions. There's no C++ mechanism used at runtime to choose, what overloaded function should be used or which template to generate... thats done while compiling...

Just avoid casting (espacialliy dynamic casting) from one type/class to another and using RTTI (Runtime Type Infomation). These things can slow down you code.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the class in front of the function definition.

```
template  <class T> T jdlMin( T a, T b )
```

should be

```
template  <class T> T Image::jdlMin( T a, T b )
```

And also, the definition MUST be in the header file, now I see your comment, that it's in the cpp.

Comment: why do you tell me it *should* and write *must* in your answer!?

Comment: You commented on my answer: "I'd say - "should", instead of "must"." And in your answer you've written: "...the definition MUST be in the header file...".

Comment: Aaaaaaah :D Sorry for the misunderstanding :D I said this for the return typo of the function, not for the definition :)

Answer (score 0):

questions without text, deserve no explaination!

```
template  <class T> T Image::jdlMin( T a, T b )
{
    return ( a < b );// ? a : b;
}
```